# Bootstrap container running off the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have the screen separated to two cols, one with width 9 and the other 3. On the right column I need a container to hold rows, but it seems that it doesn't want to stay in its col and it shoots off to the right.

If I take out the container, then all the buttons and things in that col become vertical, how can I prevent it from shooting off like that and keep the structure of the buttons to be horizontal?

Here's a small example:

http://www.bootply.com/JfUvsLOmpj

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9" id="boardArea">
    <table id="board"></table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="row" id="firstRow">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="controlPanel">
                <div class="col-md-12  text-center">
                  <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="filled">Mark</button>
                  <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="empty">Clear</button>
                  <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="unknown">Unknown</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: There are more rows on the same level as `firstRow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you've nested a `container` into the first `col-md-3` div. Containers have a set width and should only be used to wrap your rows in. So the hierarchy should go `container > row > col > row > col > row > col ...`

Comment: If I take out the container all the elements in that column become vertical, so what can be done to prevent that?

Comment: @kuhaku make the parent wider? (i.e. bigger than `.col-md-3`)

Comment: OK never mind, I had too many rows and cols, I changed it to `row > col > row ...` like you suggested and now it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
  <table class="table">
    <tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">

  <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
   <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
   <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Check out this pen: http://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/qaQVzd?editors=1100